# JSF backing bean should be serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, jsf

I'm getting these messages:

> [#|2010-07-30T11:28:32.723+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|javax.faces|_ThreadID=37;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Setting
>   non-serializable attribute value into 
>   ViewMap: (key: MyBackingBean, value
>   class:
>   foo.bar.org.jsf.MyBackingBean)|#]

Do these mean that my JSF backing beans should implement Serializable? Or are they refering to some other problem?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes, you understood it correctly. The view is basically stored in the session scope. The session scope is in JSF backed by the Servlet's [`HttpSession`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). All session attributes are supposed to implement [`Serializable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), this because the average servletcontainer may persist session data to harddisk among others to be able to share with other servers in a cluster, or to survive heavy load, or to revive sessions during server restart.

Storing raw Java objects on harddisk is only possible if the respective class implements `Serializable`. Then [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) can be used to write them to harddisk and [`ObjectInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to read them from harddisk. The servletcontainer manages this all transparently, you actually don't need to worry about it. JSF is just giving a warning so that you understand the risks.

Comment: My beans are mostly view scoped. Are they also persisted when the session is persisted?

Comment: As said, the view is stored in the session.

Comment: @BalusC, Your JSF,JavaEE answers are valuable.

Comment: @BalusC, should we serialize view beans only or view and session beans ? and what about request and application beans ?

Comment: What about injected resources such as EJB's? Would they be re-injected on ViewScoped Bean been restored and should they be marked as `transient` in this case?

Comment: @AlexErohin: EJBs are injected as serializable proxies. No need to change anything here. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/25514361

Answer (score 0):

Beans that use session, application, or conversation scope must be serializable, but beans that use request scope do not have to be serializable.
Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html

Comment: Important note: That section is about CDI managed beans, not JSF managed beans.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score -2):

Yes,
Backing Beans / Managed Beans are basically meant to persist the state of the view, so it should be implemented serialization, but UI Components may not allow it to serializable and JSF Runitime will show you errror/ warning message.
one thing you can do is mark such component transient in your MBeans.

Thanks.

Comment: This does not apply to request or application scoped JSF managed beans. As to UI components, you should simply never assign an UI component as an instance variable of a managed bean in a scope broader than the request scope. Doing so is simply bad design. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/