# Accessing SessionScoped Beans in JSF pages

Tags: session, jsf-2, managed-bean, facescontext

I am using SessionScoped Managed Beans in my application:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SampleBean{

private String value;

//getters and setters

}
```

I have my controller:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SampleController{

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{sampleBean}")
private SampleBean sampleBean;

public String showConfirm() {

return "confirm";

}

public String showComplete() {

return "complete";

}

//getters and setters
}
```

The logic is that, I have a startup page where I enter the values.Then it goes to the confirm page and then finally to the Complete page. I have to show the data entered in startup page in the remaining pages.

The startup page is as follows:

startup.xhtml

```
<h:inputText value="#{sampleBean.value}">
<h:commandLink value="Confirm"  action="#{sampleController.showConfirm()}">
```

In the confirm page, I want to show this data.

confirm.xhtml

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{sampleBean.value}">
```

However, i don't get any value displayed here.
I tried putting these values into the sessionMap in the `showConfirm()` method.

```
public String showConfirm() {

FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("sampleBean", sampleBean);

return "confirm";

}
```

But then also, I am not able to view these values in confirm.xhtml.

Only if I use `<h:outputFormat value="#{sessionScope.sampleBean.value}">` , the values get displayed.
Also, I would like to do this using **SessionScope** only since all this is part of a bigger application with sessions.
Is there an alternatve to do it?

Comment: Did you forget to use the `<h:form>` tag?

Comment: Thanks,but I have used `<h:form>` tag. I beleive I am doing someting wrong in my Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can access sessionScoped beans from views through the controller bean by :

```
<h:inputText value="#{sampleController.sampleBean.value}">
```

With adding getter/setter of this Managed-Property in the controller bean.

Comment: I tried giving `<h:outputFormat value="#{sampleController.sampleBean.value}">` in `confirm` page but its still not displaying any value.

Comment: Maybe there miss you something in the view.. can you post the view's code ?

Comment: I tried printing the sessionScope using `<h:outputFormat value="#{sessionScope}">` My `SampleController` is not displayed in the sessionscope. I believe I am doing doing something wrong in my SampleController.

Comment: Can it the managed-bean constructor ?
I tried your precise example and it runs fine, can you put the whole code of your two managed-beans + the views ?

Answer (score 0):

your session scoped bean should implement Serializable interface to work properly see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3372719/2422368)

Comment: The question's owner doesn't indicate to any exception detected; morever, the example runs fine with me without any `Serializable`'s implementation.

Comment: I tried implementing using `Serializable` interface, but yet its not working.