# Setting view scope on JSF 2.2

Tags: scope, jsf-2.2, view-scope, faces-config

On `JSF 2.2` we don't have the option to set the `View Scope` on `faces-config.xml` .

So how should it be done? Is the view scope missing on JSF 2.2 ?

Thank you!

Comment: 1st - View Scope is not missing in JSF2.2...2nd - We can set the View Scope on faces-config.xml...

Comment: What do you mean "we don't have the option to set the View Scope", are you talking about IDE let me know if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ViewScoped` annotation on managed bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AViewScopedBean {
    //managed bean contents...
}
```

If you don't like the annotations configuration (really odd), you can just set the view scope on faces-config.xml

```xml
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>aViewScopedBean<managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>some.package.AViewScopedBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Note that this **only works** on JSF 2. Check that your *faces-config* file is configured to handle JSF 2.x version:

```xml
<!-- relevant part of faces-config.xml file for this Q/A -->
<faces-config ... version="2.1">
```

---

**`Note: Warning make sure its Serializable`**

The error message is pretty straightforward:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: com.bean.StatusBean2

This means that your `com.bean.StatusBean2` must also implement the `Serializable` interface. From [`java.io.Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) documentation:

> When traversing a graph, an object may be encountered that does not support the Serializable interface. In this case the `NotSerializableException` will be thrown and will identify the class of the non-serializable object. (this is the error you're getting)

You can learn more about Java Serialization here: [Java Serialization](http://www.javabeginner.com/uncategorized/java-serialization)

From your question: *is it necessary to implement serializable?*, BalusC already posted a good answer/explanation: [JSF backing bean should be serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3372687/1065197)
Thanks for @Luiggi Mendoza